# How can I use the split() function to figure out how many vowels there are in total?

Tags: python, function, printing, split, sentence

How can I use the `split()` function to figure out how many vowels there are in total?
How can I print the number of a, e, i, o, and u in each of these sentences?
The sentence is

```
'I study Python programming at KAIST Center For Gifted Education'
```

umm.... counter is not working guys..(i mean I want you to give me details one by one, not the built-in function of the basic Python, So that it can work on other coding programs.

Comment: This shows you how much a's appear in the string.
What it does: It split the string on each "a" and then you count the length of the array you got back.

`x = len(txt.split("a"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), e.g. like this:

```py
from collections import Counter

sentence = 'I study Python programming at KAIST Center For Gifted Education'

counts = Counter(sentence)

print(counts['a'])
# 3
print(counts['A'])
# 1
print(counts['e'])
# 3
print(counts['E'])
# 1
print(counts['i'])
# 3
print(counts['I'])
# 2
print(counts['o'])
# 4
print(counts['O'])
# 0
print(counts['u'])
# 2
print(counts['U'])
# 0
```

If you'd like to count the vowels case-independently you can call `.lower()` on the sentence before passing it to `Counter()`, e.g.:

```py
from collections import Counter

sentence = 'I study Python programming at KAIST Center For Gifted Education'

counts = Counter(sentence.lower())

print(counts['a'])
# 4
print(counts['e'])
# 4
print(counts['i'])
# 5
print(counts['o'])
# 4
print(counts['u'])
# 2
```

**EDIT:**

If for some reason you cannot use the collections library, strings have a [`count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) method:

```py
sentence = 'I study Python programming at KAIST Center For Gifted Education'

print(sentence.count('a'))
# 3
print(sentence.count('e'))
# 3
print(sentence.count('i'))
# 3
print(sentence.count('o'))
# 4
print(sentence.count('u'))
# 2
```

In case you'd like to count more than just vowels, it may be more efficient to "manually" count the sub-strings (i.e. vowels in your case), e.g.:

```py
sentence = 'I study Python programming at KAIST Center For Gifted Education'

# Initialise counters:
vowels = {
    'a': 0,
    'e': 0,
    'i': 0,
    'o': 0,
    'u': 0,
}

for char in sentence:
    if char in vowels:
        vowels[char] += 1

print(vowels['a'])
# 3
print(vowels['e'])
# 3
print(vowels['i'])
# 3
print(vowels['o'])
# 4
print(vowels['u'])
# 2
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but i work in RUR-PLE so counter is not working...  any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Check this?

```
from collections import Counter
x='I study Python programming at KAIST Center For Gifted Education'
x=[a for a in x]
vowels=['a','e','i','o','u']
check_list=[]
for check in x:
    if check.lower() in vowels:
        check_list.append(check.lower())
count=Counter(check_list)
print(count)
```